# Figure not showing up in siamltex document class

Tags: graphics, epstopdf

I am working to submit to a SIAM journal and am trying to add a figure. The latex file compiles but the pdf output is blank. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[final,leqno,onefignum,onetabnum]{siamltex1213}

\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How to do you compile your `.tex` file?

Comment: Unrelated but you should not load `epsfig`. If you are using  `pdflatex` you probably need to convert the eps to pdf. But latex should never silently do nothing there should be a warning in the log if it can not handle the image

Comment: I compile the tex file using TeXShop using pdftex. I have used these packages before in this setting but with \documentclass{article} and there it compiles with no issues. So I am guessing it is a {siamltex1213} issue, however I am unable to find any documents on SIAM providing a sample figure to see what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't `graphicx` now handle the conversion automatically? It seems to for me...

Comment: @user64984 Assuming you are right, it is going to be hard for anybody to help unless you provide a link to the class you are using (since it doesn't seem to be on CTAN).

Comment: @cfr well it might if you have a new enough setup, but if the eps isn't appearing my guess is the conversion either isn't set up or the conversion failed, but the log would say....

Comment: @user64984 unless you need a compatibility with latex2.09 documents from the 1980's you should never load epsfig (honestly, I wrote that thing, you don't need it this century)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But if it really works with `article`, that suggests the installation is new enough?

Comment: @cfr always believe the log file, not the description in the question:-)

Comment: @cfr is this what you're looking for? (http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php)

Comment: The class does `\RequirePackage[dvips]{graphics,graphicx}` so it forces latex/dvips usage and makes graphics incompatible with pdflatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok Thanks. So how should I amend the code that I wrote above so that it compiles in laTeXShop. Or can you write a sample code using the class that would fix the problem?

Comment: @user64984 code is fine (apart from the useless epsfig reference) you just need to do `latex file` instead of `pdflatex file` on the command line you just type that, I have no idea how to customise which commands latexshop runs, sorry, I have never seen that editor.

Answer (score 6):

the class file loads `graphicx` and `hyperef` with explicit `dvips` options, so the intent is to use `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` to obtain PDF, not use `pdflatex`.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the quick responses and help. I downloaded texstudio which gives more options on compiling. Worked like you said, thanks again!